# Java Key Store always ends up with null aliases

Tags: java, bouncycastle, keystore, private-key, public-key

I've been trying on this for a couple of days and I'm hopelessly stuck.
To fully understand how java key store works, i've been trying to create my own keystore, put some stuff inside it, then retrieve them from another program.

Here's my keystore generator :

```
{

    //generate a X509 certificate
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("certificate.cer"));

    LOGGER.debug("BouncyCastle provider & X509 certificate added.");

    //generate a private & a public key
    KeyPair keyPair = generateRSAKeyPair();
    RSAPrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
    RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();

    //generate a keystore
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    char[] keyStorePassword = "keystore_password".toCharArray();
    ks.load(null, keyStorePassword);
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("TestKeyStore.jks")) {
        ks.store(fos, keyStorePassword);
    }

    ks.load(new FileInputStream("TestKeyStore.jks"), keyStorePassword);

    //Symmetric key
    SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry((secretKey));
    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protectionParameter = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword);
    ks.setEntry("symmetric_key", secretKeyEntry, protectionParameter);

    //Asymmetric key
    X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = new X509Certificate[1];
    x509Certificates[0] = certificate;
    ks.setKeyEntry("asymmetric key", priv, keyStorePassword, x509Certificates);

    //certificate
    ks.setCertificateEntry("test_certif", certificate);

    Key key = ks.getKey("symmetric_key", keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println("I have this symmetric key : " + key);
    X509Certificate certificate1 = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate("test_certif");
    System.out.println("I have this certificate : " + certificate1);

    System.out.println(ks.aliases().nextElement());


    LOGGER.debug("all went well");
}
```

As you probably noticed, it's not all polished: my goal *for now* is only to put some stuff inside the keystore. But the point here, from the last `System.out.println(ks.aliases().nextElement());`, is just to see there is indeed something inside the keystore. And this is working just fine, it gives back `symmetric_key`.

Now, from the same folder is another class that is supposed to read from that keystore.

Note: there is no issue regarding the file (I've tested by moving its localization) so it can't be that.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        char[] keyStorePassword = "keystore_password".toCharArray();
        ks.load(new FileInputStream("TestKeyStore.jks"), keyStorePassword);
        System.out.println(ks.containsAlias("symmetric_key"));
```

This always gets me: `false`

If I try this: `System.out.println(ks.aliases());`, it's always `null`

If I try this:

```
if (!keystore.aliases().hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println("nothing inside the keystore");
}
```

it gives me back `nothing inside the keystore`.

Even though it's not the case in the generator.

Any clue? 
Thank you

Comment: Can you open the keystore outside java? Using for instance Keystore Explorer?

Comment: @fjsv Yes, thank you your reply.
What happened with Keystore explorer :
1. I could find the keystore just fine
2. I could open it using ```keystore_password``` but there is nothing inside it.
3. I could not open it using another password (for instance, ```test```).
So I guess the initialization was okay but not the entries

Comment: This narrows the problem, but doesn't explain why the aliases were found just fine in the first place

Comment: You wrote an empty keystore, then you went to read that empty keystore, and you got nothing. That's exactly what you should have expected.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Yes exactly, and the point was to understand why it was empty in one class but not in another. My bad if it's a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the entries after writing the keystore.

If you move:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("TestKeyStore.jks")) {
    ks.store(fos, keyStorePassword);
}
```

Till after this line:

```
ks.setCertificateEntry("test_certif", certificate);
```

Everything should work fine.

Bellow you have an working example with some code removed for clarity:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyGen.initialize(2048);
    final KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();

    RSAPrivateKey priv = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

    //generate a keystore
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    char[] keyStorePassword = PASSWORD;
    ks.load(null, keyStorePassword);

    X509Certificate[] chain = {generateCertificate("cn=Unknown", keyPair, 365, "SHA256withRSA")};

    // saving one keypair in keystore object
    ks.setKeyEntry("asymmetric key", keyPair.getPrivate(), keyStorePassword, chain);

    //Symmetric key
    SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
    KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry((secretKey));
    KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protectionParameter = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword);
    // saving symmetric key in keystore object
    ks.setEntry("symmetric_key", secretKeyEntry, protectionParameter);

    // Saving our keystore object into the filesystem
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("TestKeyStore.p12")) {
        ks.store(fos, keyStorePassword);
    }
```

//        The rest of the code
    }

The reason why it works in the method that saves the keystore is because the changed keystore is still in memory, but not on the filesystem. Also, since you are creating a `PKCS12` keystore, I would avoid the `.jks` extension and go for something like `.pkcs12`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your tip, it works just fine! I'm a bit embarrassed by my mistake, but your code also come in handy for further understanding. Thanks a lot!